# Float right div intermittently pushed out of alignment - angularjs template issue?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I have a float right div within a template that loads correctly on initial page load or hard refresh.

However, on state change (using ui-router) then returning (ie swapping templates out), div gets bumped down, by what looks like a div to its left with no float.

Have I applied CSS incorrectly somehow?

Screen shots attached of both scenarios. First image is initial load, second is the page (NG template) returned after leaving via link on page. Link is a template too. The only reason I mention NG is that I've tried to recreate in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Wg7C2GuUEr1j3GlF6iO?p=preview) with conventional href links, and failed to get the error.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="locate-change">
      <input type="text" color="red" placeholder="ENTER LOCATION" class="input1" />
      <a ng-click="locateme()" href="" class="locate2">LOCATE</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.locate-change {
    float:right;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
.input1 {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:'DINLightRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    outline: none;
    width:160px;
}
.locate2 {
    float: right;
    padding-left:35px;
    background: url(../../images/locate.png);
    height: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:65px;
}
```

I can recreate the angularjs plunker if necessary.

[image: Initial page load - correct layout]

[image: Returning page - loaded via NG]

**EDIT**  a couple of notes:
- this is only happening in Chrome, not in FF or Safari
- the 'Change City' input div uses Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead which seems to add a **.dropdown-menu** class div - but it has zero dimensions   (see screenshot below)
- the empty typeahead dropdown results div code appears and is identical in both correct and incorrect states

[image: dropdown div]

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the CSS related to these elements

Comment: @Ronnie - i've added the relevant CSS to the question - it's also included in the Plunker

Comment: could you upload what you have somewhere rather than plnkr so I can take a look? Unless you can recreate it in a plnkr

Comment: have you tried to give vertical-align: top to both input and link?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez - tried it out, but no change.

Comment: Well, then limited as I am I can't help you. I'm sure there are amazing people around who could guess what happenign but limited as I am I need a fiddle, simillar or live web to replicate the problem so we could try t find a fix.(as your code in plunker coudn't). good luck

Comment: We seem to have resolved the error. I swapped the order of the 2 divs in the html and no longer getting the locate2 div pushed down. Will follow this with answer, and a theory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in how Chrome treats the [angular-ui bootstrap typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive (based on the fact that we're not seeing this error in either FF or Safari)

The order things are happening seems to be:
- on initial load, the DOM only loads existing html/CSS elements
- once the DOM is loaded, the ng directive then adds the empty typeahead dropdown div, which sits 'below' the locate2 div on the screen despite being written in the DOM between existing divs

ie as the browser reads through the DOM it places:
- input div 1st
- locate2 div 2nd
- invisible dropdown div added last via directive

On returning to the page via ui-router:
- the DOM now includes the additional dropdown element between input and locate2 divs
- each html element is treated in the order it's read in the DOM
- this means that the 'invisible' dropdown div now pushes the locate div out of the way...(in Chrome)

ie as the browser reads through the DOM on returning to the template it places:
- input div 1st
- invisible dropdown div 2nd
- locate2 div 3rd

For whatever reason, Chrome is treating the dropdown  not as a hidden div, but as a collapsed visible(?) div and pushing the locate2 div out of place.

On moving the locate2 div to before the change-city div, the injected dropdown code no longer interferes with locate2 div.

In the 'fix', as the browser reads through the DOM it places:
- locate2 div 1st
- input div 2nd
- invisible dropdown div 3rd

[image]